# NHibnerate data design recommendations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, database-design

While doing some research into mapping one-to-one relationships I've come across some statements that have made me question some of my database design decisions.

Basically I have some entities similar to the following:

Person, Contact, Parent

Both a contact and a parent are people.
A person may be a contact, parent, both, or neither.

The database design I came up with has a table for each of these three entities, and all three tables share a primary ID (PersonID). From a database design perspective, this seems to be a well-normalized and reasonably performant way to represent the database and its relationships (at least to me).

At this point, I begin coding C# classes and NHibnerate mappings to represent these entities. The most natural mapping approach I can find is to use a  mapping. The other options (one-to-one, one-to-many, etc...) seem to require that I add one or more unnecessary FK's to the tables. Upon browsing through the NHibernate documentation I stumble upon the following statement:

> This feature is often only useful for legacy data models, we recommend fewer tables than classes and a fine-grained domain model. However, it is useful for switching between inheritance mapping strategies in a single hierarchy, as explained later.

My question is:

A) Am I violating this principal?
  B) If so, how would I better design this system?

Is this statement suggesting that I should lump all of the Person/Contact/Parent fields into a single table (with many nullable fields)? Or am I somehow missing the point?

Since this is a rare occasion where I can design the tables/classes from scratch I would like to get it right. Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: More info about how I intend the above database design to work:

The basic idea is that every person gets a record in the person table. The presence/absence of records in the related tables determines whether the person is a parent, contact, etc... This would seem to enforce the one->one relationships and allow for fast queries/joins (the shared primary ID would be a clustered PK in each table).

Edit: Thanks for the help guys. I didn't really consider queryability well enough when I designed this system so I'm going to move toward something similar to the solutions suggested by Jamie Ide & hlgem. I found all answers helpful. All in all it looks like shared primary keys result in some problems with the object model on the c# side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this depends on how you intend to query that data. If you want to easily be able to see what roles a person plays wihout the details specific to a role, then have a roles table. To see all the roles a person has, just two tables need to be joined no matter how many roles you later add. Otherwise, you will have to join to every one of the specialty tables (left joins in case they don't exist) just to see what roles a person has. Not so good for performance.

We have lots of these types of relationships in our database and we have a person table with an id, a roles table with the id and the role id in it and a role type table that is a lookup for the roles. And then specialty tables that have the information for a specific role such as sales reps or sales targets.  Each table has it's own id and each table (except the lookup table) includes the id from the person table which is set as a foreign key. (Trust me there is very rarely such a thing as unnecessary foreign keys, the converse is not true, missing an FK when you should have one is bad news.)

Now you could still have the foreign key relationship using just the PK from the parent table as both the Fk to the person table and the PK of the specialty table but I recommend against it. In any event, if you don't set up an FK to the person table, you data is doomed to data integrity issues. I prefer to use the surrogate keys and thus always set my own key on each table. It prevents many redesign issues in the long run. If you want to maintain the one-to-one relationship, a simple unique index on the field is all you need. The table moves from one-to-one to one-to-many and all you need to do is drop the index. If you were using it as your PK as well, then you need a new PK and all the code referencing the pk has to be changed. Adding a new PK to a table with 150,000,000 records, not a fun task.

Answer (score 2):

Your database design needs a bit of work; here's my suggestion.

It's good that you've got the idea that Contact and Parent can both be Persons; however, you need for Contact and Parent to have distinct Primary Keys.  You can enforce the requirement that they both have Parent IDs with a non-nullable Foreign Key in the Contact and Parent tables that refers to the Person ID of the entry in the Person table.

So the Person table should have a unique Primary Key (its ID) and any other relevant columns.  The Contact table should have its own unique Primary Key (its ID), a non-nullable Foreign Key reference to the Person table (the ID in the Person table) and any other relevant columns.  The Parent table should have its own unique Primary Key (its ID), and a non-nullable Foreign Key reference to the Person table (the ID in the Person table) and any other relevant columns.

This should solve your mapping problems.  If you need, you can use a View to "recombine" your Person / Parent / Contact "constellation" (collection of related tables).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I agree that this would solve my mapping problems. However, I think that this makes things "uglier" from the database design side. Since all of these relationships should be one-to-one (perhaps I should have made this clear in the initial post), your suggestion seems to introduce a lot of unnecessary FK's into the model. On top of this it makes the relationships one->many instead of one->one - the initial design would enforce correct cardinality.

Comment: @Krazzy: to be honest, it's a little bit difficult to suggest the design without an understanding of the scope of your tables; since I don't know how many columns Person, Parent, and Contact have, it's tough to tell what might be a good design.  Based upon your feedback, perhaps you'd be better off merging the Parent and Contact tables with the Person table, and use a View to recover Parents and Contacts as needed?  (This is essentially the converse of my original suggestion...)

Comment: @Krayzzy:  In any event, the fundamental problem is the sharing of the primary key.  A good general rule (and one which Hibernate uses extensively) is to have a distinct Primary Key for every table.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about inheritance mapping, not a one-to-one relationship. Your design requires [table-per-subclass](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-8/1nr4enxv3dpeq/11#8%282E%291%282E%292%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Table_per_subclass) mapping, but I'm unsure how to address the requirement that a Person can be both a Contact and a Parent. I don't know of a good way to model this except to introduce another subclass covering both roles. Think of it this way, if you ask your repository to return a Person and that Person is both a Contact and a Parent, which type should it return?

If you do stick to subclassing then I would recommend sticking to [table-per-class](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-8/1nr4enxv3dpeq/11#8%282E%291%282E%291%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Table_per_class_hierarchy) if possible.

But a better design might be to introduce a "role" table and have a one-to-many relationship between Person and Role.

Edited to add: IMHO, your current design won't work. What type of object would represent a Person who is both a Contact and a Parent?

Instead of a simple role table, you could use a "complicated" role table(s) that included the additional data. You could have a set of Role objects (ContactRole, ParentRole, etc.), each containing the fields associated with that role. A Person object would then have a collection of Role objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Because of the reasons you mention, inheritance is not an option. Also, there may be many more types of "people" introduced in the future, making the introduction of a subclass to handle each possibility unwieldy. A simple role table will not quite work either because each "role" requires associated data unique to the role.

Comment: Thanks again for the help - the intent is that the presence/absence of a record in a related table will indicate whether a person is of a given type. Therefore, for a Person who is both a Contact and a Parent, a record of Person, Contact, and Parent will be present in the respective tables.

Comment: That's (arguably) reasonable on the database side, but difficult to implement on the object oriented side. Since you're working with NHibernate, I suggest that you work out the domain model and examine what database schema would best support your model.